# Calculating and improving time and memory complexity

Tags: java, complexity

```
private static int Sum (int[] a, int from, int to){
   int total=0;
   for (int i=from; i <= to; i++)
       res += a[i];
   return total;
}

public static int Method3 (int []a){
    int temp=0;
    for (int i=0; i <= a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j <= a.length; j++)
        {
           int c = Sum(a,i,j);
           if (c%3 == 0)
           {
            if (j-i+1 > temp)
            temp = j-i+1;
           }
        }
    }
return temp;
}
```

The purpose of `Method3` method is to find the longest combination of a given array numbers', so that the sum of the numbers of the combination can be divided by 3 without remainder.

1. How do I make it more efficient in terms of both time and memory complexity?
2. How do I even approach to something like this?
3. ow can I know that the complexity I've reached is the best possible?

Comment: Consider carefully what happens in these three cases: i=1, j=1; i=1, j=2; i=2, j=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make it much more efficient by using a completely different algorithm. The idea is to take a closer look at prefix sums. Let's assume that a subarray `[L, R]` is divisible by 3. It means that `prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L - 1] == 0 (mod 3)`, or `prefixSum[R] == prefixSum[L - 1] (mod 3)`. It results in a simple solution: iterating over all elements of the array from left to right and maintaining the current prefix sum modulo 3 and keeping track of the first occurrence of each value modulo 3. The code can look like this:

```
int getLongestSubarray(int[] a) {
    int[] firstOccurrence = new int[3];
    firstOccurrence[0] = -1;
    firstOccurrence[1] = a.length;
    firstOccurrence[2] = a.length;
    int prefixSum = 0;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        prefixSum = (prefixSum + a[i]) % 3;
        if (prefixSum < 0)
            prefixSum += 3;
        result = Math.max(result, i - firstOccurrence[prefixSum]);
        firstOccurrence[prefixSum] = Math.min(firstOccurrence[prefixSum], i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The time complexity is `O(n)` and the space complexity is `O(1)`. It is optimal because it is not possible to find the longest subarray divisble by 3 without seeing all elements of the input array.

Comment: At first I thought I understood it, but looking at it carefully now made me realize I haven't fully gotten the idea behind your algorithm. Can you please explain it to me again?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @BinaryJ The idea: take a look at prefix sums. sum(l, r) = prefixSum(r) - prefixSum(l - 1). Now we want to find a zero modulo 3. It means that prefixSum(r) == prefixSum(l  - 1) modulo 3. If you have any questions, could you please tell me which specific part of this algorithm you do not fully understand?

Comment: I think I understand the idea, just having a bit of a hard time fully understanding the implementation part, though. 
More precisely, the last part where you set values to result and firstOccurence. 
Also, if the array is {1,2,3,4}, doesn't the iteration only checks 1, 1+2 , 1+2+3 and 1+2+3+4 ? for example, for the combination 3+4, does it cover that possibility as well?

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @BinaryJ For {1, 2, 3, 4} the prefix sums(modulo 3) are {1, 0, 0, 1}. firstOccurrence = {-1, 0, 4}(because 2 never appears). 3 + 4 is not checked(it is not divisible, anyway), but 2 + 3 + 4 is checked.

Comment: I'm trying to do it step by step.. 
why is firstOccurence[0] is -1 at the beginning?

Comment: @Bin Because a sum for an empty prefix is 0. We use 0 indexation for the array, so it has a -1 index.

Comment: I understand the result when firstOcc is 0, but when 1 or 2 , not so much..
for example , {1,2,3,4} :
i=0 : result = max(0,0-foc[1]) -> 0 ; foc[1]=0

;;i=1 : result = max(0,1-foc[0]) -> 2 ; foc[0]=-1

;;i=2 : result = max(2,2-foc[0]) -> 3 ; foc[0]=-1

;;i=3 : result = max(3,3-foc[1]) -> 3 ; foc[0]=-1

Now , I understand i=1 and i=2 ,because prefixSum is 0 ,then it's like you said in the beginning : prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L - 1] == 0.

But why in i=3, when prefixSum is 1 , you still look for that difference in 'result' : i-foc[1] ?

Comment: @BinaryJ When i = 3, I want to find the first element with the same prefix sum(that is, 1). That's why it is 3 - foc[1]

Comment: But why? for example if I add to 1,2,3,4 another 3 so the new array is 1,2,3,4,3 , in i=3 my result will still be 3 , but in i=4 it will be 4 . How does it know we had foc[1] three times ? (unless the idea here is something else)

Comment: @BinaryJ It does not matter how many times. Only the first occurrence and the current value matters.